# Change font to comicneue only for one sentence

Tags: fonts

I am trying to change the font from helvetica to comicneue only for one sentence. I want to use pdflatex. I do not know the fontcode to get that done with a `\renewcommand{\fontfamiliy}{fontcode}`. 
If I set a `\usepackage{default}{comicneue}` the whole document is in that font, of course. So how would that be possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[default]{comicneue}

\begin{document}

\familydefault

\end{document}
```

prints

[image]

OK, that's the missing bit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\comicneue}{\fontfamily{ComicNeue-TLF}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textcomicneue}{\comicneue}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]

{\comicneue\lipsum[3]}

\lipsum[4]

\textcomicneue{\lipsum[5]}

\end{document}
```

[image]