# Change doi font style to Times New Roman biblatex

Tags: biblatex, fonts, url

I am trying to change doi font style to Times New Roman. By default, the font is not in Times New Roman but something else. I have tried:

```
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\TNR}{\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textTNR}{\TNR}

\DeclareFieldFormat{doi}{ %
    \color{black}{doi}%
  \mkbibacro{}\addcolon \selectfont
  \textTNR{\underline{
  \ifhyperref
    {\href{https://doi.org/#1}{\nolinkurl{#1}}}
    {\nolinkurl{#1}}
    }
    }
    }
```

I have the above code by the following references link:
[1] [Change font to comicneue only for one sentence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414731/change-font-to-comicneue-only-for-one-sentence)
[2] [Formatting only the DOI using biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/446145/formatting-only-the-doi-using-biblatex)

Can anyone point out what's wrong with the above? I appreciate your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your document is already set up for Times (or with a Times clone), you only need `\urlstyle{same}` to have URLs, DOIs and the like in the main document font.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\urlstyle{same}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: DOI in Times]